# create a group from selected tableview cells

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am trying to send the checked rows from my table view into a newly created group to my firebase database, once the user selects the rows and the checkmark is displayed, how can I send the selected rows information to my database. I am not sure if I should be doing this in the didSelectRowAt function or to add a "create group" button once the rows are selected. Any information will be helpful thank you.

```
import UIKit

 class FriendsViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

 var userList = [Users]()

@IBOutlet weak var myTableView: UITableView!

final let urlString = "https://api.lookfwd.io/v1/test/users"

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return userList.count

}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let myCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! MyTableViewCell
    myCell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.none
    myCell.nameLabel.text = userList[indexPath.row].name
    return myCell
}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

  self.downloadJsonWithTask()


}

 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if myTableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryType.checkmark{

        myTableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.none}
    else{
        myTableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.checkmark
    }

    }



func downloadJsonWithTask() {

    let url = NSURL(string: urlString)

    var downloadTask = URLRequest(url: (url as URL?)!, cachePolicy: URLRequest.CachePolicy.reloadIgnoringCacheData, timeoutInterval: 20)

    downloadTask.httpMethod = "GET"

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: downloadTask, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) -> Void in

        if let response = data {
            if let jsonData = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: response, options: .allowFragments) as? [String:Any] {

                if let dataArray = (jsonData as AnyObject).value(forKey: "users") as? [[String:Any]] {
                    for data in dataArray{
                        let newUser = Users(data: data)
                        self.userList.append(newUser)
                        print(jsonData!)
                    }
                }
                OperationQueue.main.addOperation({
                    for use in self.userList {
                        print(use.name ?? "")
                    }
                    self.myTableView.reloadData()

                })

                print(jsonData!)
            }
        }
    }).resume()
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The best way to achieve this to add a button instead of checkbox, set the images of checkbox for the selected and default state of button and in your "cellForRowAt" method do this:

In your "cellForRowAt" method:

```
 let button = cell.viewWithTag(123) as? UIButton // 123 is tag that is defined in Stoyboard for this button/checkbox.
 button.accessibilityHint = "\(indexPath.row)"
 button.addTarget(self, action: "action:", forControlEvents: 
 UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
```

Paste this method any where in your ViewController:

```
 func action(sender:UIButton!) {

 let position = Int(sender.accessibilityHint) // This is the position that will help you to get the specific item from your list.

 if (sender.selected == true)
{
 sender.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "box"), forState: 
UIControlState.Normal)
sender.selected = false
// Remove from Datbase
}
  else
{
  sender.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "checkBox"), forState: 
 UIControlState.Normal)
sender.selected = true
  // Add into database.
 }
 }
```

This is a method of a button directly connected from Storyboard to ViewController. For your table view you have o follow these steps:

1. Get your button in "cellForIndexAt" method with Tag.
2. Set "accessibilityHint" of your button with "indexPath.row".
3. Add target to your button.
4. Get the position through "accessibilityHint" in your targeted method.
5. Use logic given above in your targeted method.

But if you don't want to go through all this process then simply add your item in databse in your "didSelectRowAt" method, but it will perform the action wherever user taps on the whole cell.

Comment: you're suggesting adding a button inside each cell?

Comment: Yes, if you want to add and remove the data on the click of checkbox then use Button, otherwise if you want to add data when user clicks anywhere on the whole cell then do it in "didSelectRowAt" method.

Comment: I'm having trouble implementing this method, can you elaborate your instructions for #2 and #4. How can I check which cells are selected so I can send those over to firebase?

Comment: I have edited my answer and implemented the 2nd and 4th step.

Comment: so i just need to put the first method into my cellForRow function, and paste the second method anywhere into view controller? and that is all?

Comment: Yeah, but in the second method when you will get the position you have to add or remove the data from your database.

Comment: i have an error on this line  button.accessibilityHint = /(indexPath.row)
stating / is not a prefix unirary operator

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147576/discussion-between-zohaib-hassan-and-user8000557).

Comment: It was a typo, I updated that line. Check the updated one.